# Border with border-radius specified refusing to print in Opera?

Tags: printing, opera, css

I'm not certain if this is something I'm doing wrong or if it's just a bug in the way Opera handles printing, but here's my problem:

I print reports for my company that are written in PHP and include a simple stylesheet (with alternatives for screen and print media).

Everything seems to work fine, the report displays on the screen correctly and the printed version is *almost* perfect. The issue I'm having is that I'm using a div to encapsulate data tables, and the div has a border with a radius to make it look not-so-blockish. When I go to print (via print-to-pdf or directly printing to the printer) the border around the div will not print. The table borders work fine, but not the div.

I discovered that if I included in the printed media an exclusion on the radius then it prints fine (but not as pretty). It should be noted that on Chrome the div border prints fine regardless.

So.. anyone have any ideas? I'm stumped.

Comment: It's a bug, https://bugs.opera.com/browse/DSK-355093.

Comment: Cool, but I can't see the bug, trying to figure out now how I can get access to actually view it.

Comment: Sorry, you can't because Opera's bug tracker is closed. You can however ask Erik or myself questions about it. Apologies for the closed-source workflow.